# Is it possible to turn a png into a layered PSD file?

Tags: image, image-processing, png, photoshop, psd

I have a PNG image that I would like to turn into a layered PSD image. The image itself is mostly white space with several areas of text.

I tried to convert this PNG to a PSD but I ended up with a flat image.

I am not too versed in image processing. Is there any service that can recognize areas of white space and turn the various components of an image into layers?

Comment: No, a PNG does not have layers. And the "areas of white space" is a fuzzy concept. YOu must do it yourself.

Comment: Let's assume you have darker objects on a white background. Are you asking how you can remove the white background (replace with transparent pixels) ? Also, why would you need multiple layers ? Do you need to place each isolated remaining 'island' of dark pixels on a separate layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry png or jpeg files cannot be converted into layers . For this, you need to break the image into layers and then convert the file as .psd

Answer (score 0):

Yes .PNG can be layered (from Macromedia Fireworks back in the day) 
I still have about 100,000 layered files in .PNG 
If I remember right Corel Draw can convert these files.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the OP. Is this mean as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in Adobe Fireworks CS6 .PNG format.

1. Save your document with the Photoshop layers in .PSD format in a folder
2. Open saved .PSD with Adobe Fireworks CS6
3. In Fireworks CS6, click 'File' then 'Save As' and select the first 'Fireworks .PNG' format option. You will notice that the name of your file will have the following extensions: [name.fw.png].
4. Save

PS. Never Save to "PNG level.PNG" because the layers will be unified. Just like it should not be exported to any .PNG. That is, just save the .PSD document to .FW.PNG.